# AngularJS animating element

Tags: angularjs, animation, angular-material

I would like to add some animations to my angularjs applications, and surfing on dribble I found this example:

[image: material design animation]

Can someone point me to the right direction for achieving this effect ? Are there some libs doing the work or is it entirely artisanal ?

Notice the 2 animations, the one from the front yellow button expanding to the full area, and the back area sliding/fading away

Comment: I think you will find that this isn't actually the button morphing into another element - but simply that it disappears and a yellow pane fades in. If i was building this, I'd look at this kind of structure:
1. button gets clicked and moves to the centre of the bottom pane - then becomes invisible
2. bottom pane slides left to hide times/dates
3. another pane fades in with some kind of animation

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you an example, you can change the effects to meet your needs!

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'fmp-card']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.leftBackText = 'Here you can insert anything you want, may be a page!';
    $scope.rightBackText = "http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=41f6e13ade69";
});
```

```css
.my-card{
    display: inline-block;
}

.back-text{
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#container{
  width: 100%;  
}

#card-1{
    float: left;
}

#card-2{
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title>AngularJS Flip Card</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://rawgit.com/souly1/angular-flip-card/master/css/fmpCardDirective.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.3.6"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-animate@*" data-semver="1.3.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/souly1/angular-flip-card/master/fmpCardDirective.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="container">
    <fmp-card class="my-card" id="card-1" suffix="left" image="http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=41f6e13ade69" front-caption="Left Card" small-card-width="200px" small-card-height="200px">
      <div class="back-text"><img src={{rightBackText}} /></div>
    </fmp-card>
    <fmp-card class="my-card" id="card-2" suffix="right" image="http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=41f6e13ade69" front-caption="Right Card" small-card-width="200px" small-card-height="200px">
      <div class="back-text">{{leftBackText}}</div>
    </fmp-card>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your example, but my question is more about the button morphing to an element and vice-versa than simple animation.